# Simple&Basic JS - 1st attempt to javascript (want it jQuery free)

Tags: javascript

First attempt to javascript.. not sure what I'm doing wrong...
Trying to clear the "Sample Here" when i hover mouse or focus, or click.
And Alert when the button is clicked..

I'd rather advices how I can avoid using functions inside the HTML and use them 
under the  to separate js/html completely!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Script Practicing</title>
</style>
<script>

    document.onreadystatechange = function ()
       {
         if (document.readyState == "complete")
         {
            //Page Loaded

            function go()
            {
                alert("done");
            }

            function clear()
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
                x = "";
            }
         }
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post">
            <input  onclick="clear();" type="text" id="x" value="Sample here" />
            <button onclick="go();">Click !</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on a general education note, HTML5 documents (i.e. documents that start with `<!doctype html>`) do not need `type="text/javascript"` as script element attribute.

Comment: appreciate the comment.. I fixed that.. any advice about the rest?

Comment: yup, answer posted. It might be worth looking at how other sites/projects do this, too, though. JS is fairly "simple" but finding good tutorials/examples requires a bit of googling (w3schools, for instance, is not a good resource here)

Comment: you probably want `onfocus` instead of `onclick` for the input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your functions from the html as you are doing, you need them to be in the global scope.

Take the definitions for the functions `go()` and `clear()` out of the `onreadystatechange` function. You can still use that function to *call* the other two, but they must be defined globally.

Also, you cannot simply change the value of the variable `x` and have that update the element with id=x on the page. Instead, you can use `ELEMENT.setAttribute('value', '')` to clear the value.

```
function go() {
  alert("done");
}

function clear() {
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  x.setAttribute('value', '');
}    

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    go();
    clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 documents don't require you state type for a `<script>` element if it's javascript, and you want to state which character set your document is going to use. This is pretty much always going to be utf8.

That said, you want to tap into the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Java Script Practicing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input  class="userinput" type="text" value="Sample here" />
      <button class="gobutton">Click !</button>
    </form>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var button = document.querySelector("button.gobutton");
      button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        console.log("button was clicked");
      }):

      var input = document.querySelector("input.userinput");
      input.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        input.value = "";
      }):
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't i do the whole script under the header instead?

Comment: you can, but there's no point: anything in the `<head>` holds up the rest of the page loading, and the script you're using can't even run until the rest of the page is done loading. The current best practice is to move scripts like that to the end of your document, so you don't hold up the browser. Content first, then scripts.

Comment: also remember to mark an answer as the correct one by hitting the big green checkmark, too (if one of these are what you were looking for) so that your question doesn't show up in "no acceptable answer yet" lists =)

Answer (score 0):

Mike has answered your question. Just explaining why your way didn't work. Your functions (go, clear) have become local to the onreadystatechange's callback function's scope. I.e a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)